# Facebook Tab with Fat Free Framework

Tags: php, facebook, fat-free-framework

Is there some limitation with Fat Free Framework when we try to output the page into facebook tab?

I already try it with this below code, and unfortunately in the facebook tab iframe always empty blank page.

```
<?php

$f3=require('app/lib/base.php');

require_once 'app/lib/fb/facebook.php';

$f3->route('GET /',
    function() {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
);
$f3->route('GET /landing',
    function() {
        $app_id = 'xxxx';
        $secret_key = 'yyyy';
        $page_id = 'zzzz';

        $config = array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $secret_key
        );

        $fb = new Facebook($config);

        $fbdata = $fb->getSignedRequest();

        $fbInPage = false;
        if(!empty($fbdata) && is_array($fbdata)
            && !empty($fbdata['page']) && is_array($fbdata['page'])
            && !empty($fbdata['page']['id'])
        ) {
            $fbInPage = $fbdata['page']['id'];
        }

        // Check if user not in fb tab
        if(!$fbInPage) {
            // Redirect to facebook tab
            echo '<script>window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/'.
                $page_id.
                '?sk=app_'.
                $app_id.
                '"</script>';
            exit;
        }

        // Get User ID
        $user = $fb->getUser();

        // Check if user not connected to facebook
        if ($user) {
            try {
                $user_data = $fb->api("/me");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user_data = null;
            }
        } else {
            // Asking permission for email and user_likes
            $fb_login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email, user_likes'
            ));

            echo '<script>top.location.href = "'.$fb_login_url.'"</script>';
            exit;
        }
    }
);

$f3->run();
```

First when user try to access `GET /landing` it will redirect to facebook tab and show the page `GET /`. But somehow it always return empty page, already inspect it with firebug on firefox and there is no error, on the response tab always shows `Reload the page to get source for: https://localhost/f3-fb/`. Already try it with my office framework and works perfectly.

If anybody ever get this problem please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in `XFRAME`, on default F3 set the `XFRAME` value as `SAME-ORIGIN`, based on this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options), developer must overload the value with `ALLOW-FROM uri`.

Here is the full code for index.php:

```
<?php

$f3=require('app/lib/base.php');

require_once 'app/lib/fb/facebook.php';

$f3->set('XFRAME', 'ALLOW-FROM https://localhost/f3-fb/');

$f3->route('POST /',
    function() {
        echo 'Hello';
    }
);

$f3->route('GET /landing',
    function() {
        $app_id = 'xxxx';
        $secret_key = 'yyyy';
        $page_id = 'zzzz';

        $config = array(
            'appId' => $app_id,
            'secret' => $secret_key
        );

        $fb = new Facebook($config);

        $fbdata = $fb->getSignedRequest();

        $fbInPage = false;
        if(!empty($fbdata) && is_array($fbdata)
            && !empty($fbdata['page']) && is_array($fbdata['page'])
            && !empty($fbdata['page']['id'])
        ) {
            $fbInPage = $fbdata['page']['id'];
        }

        // Check if user not in fb tab
        if(!$fbInPage) {
            // Redirect to facebook tab
            echo '<script>window.location.href="https://www.facebook.com/'.
                $page_id.
                '?sk=app_'.
                $app_id.
                '"</script>';
            exit;
        }

        // Get User ID
        $user = $fb->getUser();

        // Check if user not connected to facebook
        if ($user) {
            try {
                $user_data = $fb->api("/me");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user_data = null;
            }
        } else {
            // Asking permission for email and user_likes
            $fb_login_url = $fb->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email, user_likes'
            ));

            echo '<script>top.location.href = "'.$fb_login_url.'"</script>';
            exit;
        }
    }
);

$f3->run();
```

Add the config `$f3->set('XFRAME', 'ALLOW-FROM https://localhost/f3-fb/');` to allow this url inside on facebook iframe.

And always use `POST` for the route inside the facebook iframe (still don't know why must using that with F3, but it will occur the error and asking for `POST` route)